# Source of a parabolic wavefront

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, diffraction

The Huygens-Fresnel diffraction integral has been formulated for incident spherical waves.
A source of a spherical wave is kind of intuitive, since the perpendicular rays of the sphere converge into a single point, which we can call the punctual source.

On the other hand, if we approximate the Huygens-Fresnel principle into parabolic -or paraboloidal- wavefronts (Fresnel diffraction), how can we understand the source of such wavefront, by the fact that the normal lines of the paraboloid does not converge into a single point?

Comment: Why do you need to know ? I mean, do you think you need it for further calculations, or you are just curious whether and how it is possible ? (BTW it could result of parallel or spherical wavefronts after reflection or refraction on a dedicated shape).

Comment: because parabolic waves look like they are more realistic, since punctual sources do not exist, I expect the parabolic wavefront are produced not by a punctual source but a spot with some dimension, namely the Fresnel diffraction would be an approximation to non punctual sources.

Comment: well, the very notion of unique front (= all in phase) might be ill-posed, then.

Comment: I suspect the parabolic front is just the first added complexity to linear front in the spirit of Taylor series. (but maybe I'm wrong).